# What are the green shoots coming out from under my tree?

Tags: trees, roots

I just moved into my first house, :) and I have two big bushy trees in the front yard. (I'm unsure of the identification for them. Anyone know?)

At one time it looks like they were lanscaped, but since have started growing sturdy green shoots from the base.  See below pictures.  Am I safe to hack that weed like thing out of there?  It's pretty tough.  Any recommendations how to do this if that is so?  (Ax?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder whether that root barrier might be bad for the tree.  It's pretty close - well within the dripline, if I'm seeing it right.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my guess at what you're looking at.  The tree took a huge amount of damage some time in the past as evidenced by the dark line running up the trunk.  I'm guessing this is a grafted tree and after the damage the original root system decided to ditch it's partner further up the trunk and grow it's own leaves.  From the thickness of the little stems this was allowed to grow for some time.

- Dig the sucker growth out back to the trunk while trying to minimize damage to the root system.
- try and identify the tree. We need location and a closeup of the leaf and bark
- consider doing some pruning to let more light in and promote new growth on the upper part of the tree.  If you don't know how consider an arborist or landscaper or ask another question here.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a fruit tree of some kind, probably apple.  I don't think it's pear, cherry, or peach, and I can't think what else it could be.

I agree with @kevinsky on the suckers.

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question, the answer is **yes it is safe to bring those weed out**. The root of your tree won't damage by bringing the weeds out.